# Merge and group rows from multiple 2d arrays based on a shared column value then push another column's data into subarrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge, grouping

Scenario:

**I have these 2 arrays**:

`array1`:

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [label] => pending
        [fillColor] => #468847
        [data] => 50
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [label] => dispatched
        [fillColor] => #6ecf70
        [data] => 10
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [label] => delivered
        [fillColor] => #f89406
        [data] => 1
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [label] => invoiced
        [fillColor] => #3a87ad
        [data] => 2
    )

)
```

`array2`:

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [label] => pending
        [fillColor] => #468847
        [data] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
            )

    )

)
```

**The result I need is**

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [label] => pending
        [fillColor] => #468847
        [data] => Array
            (
                [0] => 50
                [1] => 1
            )
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [label] => dispatched
        [fillColor] => #6ecf70
        [data] => Array
            (
                [0] => 10
                [1] => 0
            )
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [label] => delivered
        [fillColor] => #f89406
        [data] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 0
            )
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [label] => invoiced
        [fillColor] => #3a87ad
        [data] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2
                [1] => 0
            )
    )

)
```

There are only 4 labels:

- `pending`
- `dispatched`
- `delivered`
- `invoiced`

**Please note that the arrays are just an example. It can happen that the first array has no values at all or just 2 and the second array have 3 values or none.**

Because of that constraint above I'm thinking to use `array_replace` and having an array called

```
base_array = ["pending", "dispatched", "delivered", "invoiced"]
```

I have tried to loop the `base_array` and try to match the `array1` with `array2` if label exist.

**Basically, if key (which is label) is not exist in any of `array1` or `array2` then the value replaced will be 0 in the resulting array.**

I have tried

```
foreach($base_array as $key => $value) {
    if(in_array($key, $array1[$key])) {
        $array[$key] = $array1[$key];
    }
}
```

but it looks like I'm lost on these multi dimensional arrays and replacing. Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: can you explain your result array data key ? what will be your expected result ?

Comment: The expected array result is above. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I have rewrite the SQL query and get better array in return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i understand from your question you can do it like this :-

```
    $array = array(
    '1' => Array
        (
        'label' => 'pending',
        'fillColor' => '#468847',
        'data' => '50'
    ),
    '2' => Array
        (
        'label' => 'dispatched',
        'fillColor' => '#6ecf70',
        'data' => '10'
    ),
    '3 ' => Array
        (
        'label' => 'delivered',
        'fillColor' => '#f89406',
        'data' => '1'
    ),
    '4' => Array
        (
        'label' => 'invoiced',
        'fillColor' => '#3a87ad',
        'data' => '2'
    ),
);

$array2 = array
    (
    '1' => Array
        (
        'label' => 'pending',
        'fillColor' => '#468847',
        'data' => array
            (
            '0' => '1'
        )
    )
);

$temp = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

    $temp[$key]['label'] = $value['label'];
    $temp[$key]['fillColor'] = $value['fillColor'];

    foreach ($array2 as $key2 => $value2) {

        if ($value['fillColor'] == $value2['fillColor'] && $value['label'] == $value2['label']) {
            $temp[$key]['data'][] = $value['data'];
            if (isset($value2['data'][$i])) {
                $temp[$key]['data'][] = $value2['data'][$i];
            }
        } else {
            $temp[$key]['data'][] = $value['data'];
            if (!isset($value2['data'][$i])) {
                $temp[$key]['data'][] = 0;
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($temp);
```

Comment: It is working for the arrays I gave but not the general case. The print_r($temp) return Array ( [1] => Array ( [label] => pending [fillColor] => #468847 [data] => Array ( [0] => 50 [1] => 1 ) ) [2] => Array ( [label] => dispatched [fillColor] => #6ecf70 ) [3 ] => Array ( [label] => delivered [fillColor] => #f89406 ) [4] => Array ( [label] => invoiced [fillColor] => #3a87ad ) )

Comment: please explain your expected result so that i can help more

Comment: The expected temp array is to have "data" as an array with 0 if not found. Thank you for your time. I have rewrite the SQL query and get better array in return.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
$array1 = array(
    array(
        'label'     => 'pending',
        'fillColor' => '#468847',
        'data'      => '50'
    ),
    array(
        'label'     => 'dispatched',
        'fillColor' => '#468847',
        'data'      => '10'
    ),
    array(
        'label'     => 'delivered',
        'fillColor' => '#468847',
        'data'      => '8'
    ),
    array(
        'label'     => 'invoiced',
        'fillColor' => '#468847',
        'data'      => '5'
    )

);
$array2 = array(
    array(
        'label'     => 'pending',
        'fillColor' => '#468847',
        'data'      => array()
    ),
    array(
        'label'     => 'dispatched',
        'fillColor' => '#6ecf70',
        'data'      => array()
    ),
    array(
        'label'     => 'delivered',
        'fillColor' => '#f89406',
        'data'      => array()
    ),
    array(
        'label'     => 'invoiced',
        'fillColor' => '#3a87ad',
        'data'      => array()
    )
);

foreach ($array1 as $order) {
    foreach ($array2 as $key => $group) {
        if ($order['label'] == $group['label']) {
            array_push($array2[$key]['data'], $order['data']);
        }
    }
}

var_dump($array2);
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I have rewrite the SQL query and get better array in return. BTW it is not working.

Comment: It works but not give the expected result. See answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Declare an array of default rows with empty `data` values.

Merge the default array, the first array, thrn the second array into one array.

Iterate the merged array's rows.

Declare reference arrays which are identified by `label` values.  Explicitly cast each encountered `data` value as an array before joining into its group's subarray.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/bBZhP))

```
$defaults = [
    ['label' => 'pending', 'fillColor' => '#468847', 'data' => []],
    ['label' => 'dispatched', 'fillColor' => '#6ecf70', 'data' => []],
    ['label' => 'delivered', 'fillColor' => '#f89406', 'data' => []],
    ['label' => 'invoiced', 'fillColor' => '#3a87ad', 'data' => []],
];

$result = [];
foreach (array_merge($defaults, $array1, $array2) as $row) {
    $label = $row['label'];
    $row['data'] = (array) $row['data'];
    if (!isset($ref[$label])) {
        $ref[$label] = $row;
        $result[] = &$ref[$label];
    } else {
        $ref[$label]['data'] = array_merge(
            $ref[$label]['data'],
            $row['data']
        );
    }
}
var_export($result);
```